# vimeo autoplay=1 no longer working in Chrome

Tags: iframe, vimeo, autoplay

I recently developed a website that has a streaming video as its full-screen background that autoplays & loops when the website loads. It was working in Chrome until very recently. Google changed their policy on autoplaying video in April, so I believe this may be the reason. The new google policy says that muted video is still allowed to autoplay, but that doesn't seem to be helping me (I already had it muted). The video still autoplays and loops in Firefox.

The code that I'm using to stream the video is as follows:

```html
<iframe  class="embed-responsive-item" 
src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/240749191?muted=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&background=1" 
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The website is live at [Hypempire.com](http://www.hypempire.com)

Comment: This can happen because you have an HTTPS iframe embedded on your HTTP site. Try replacing the iframe's src from https to http and refresh the page, the background video should work!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That worked perfectly.

Comment: And now autostream isn't working again. Initially that tweak helped, but now it's back to being a static image. Hm...

Comment: Try removing the additional muted, autoplay, and loop parameters - in other words, only use the background parameter. The background param will automatically mute, autoplay, and loop the video, so using those parameters is unnecessary.